# how to make android date picker to not allow past date being picked

Tags: java, android, date

I am using [Date picker](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-datepicker.html).
How do we check if today and the past date cannot be selected?
In php, we can compare using `strtotime(now)` and selected date and deduce whether it's past date or not.

Is it possible to do on Android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you have obtained the value just do:

```
Date fromPicker = // get the value here;
Date now = new Date();
if (fromPicker.before(now)) {
  // error !
}
```

Comment: hello, i am new in java and android prgramming as well, may i know how we can get the value here fromPicker?

Comment: According to p. 6 of your link, you have mYear, mMonth, mDay. Use Calendar class to build a date from them.